# Get delta of current date and column's timestamp - does not exist: double precision - timestamp without time zone

Tags: postgresql-9.5

columns created_at, modified_at type **timestamp** without timezone

Get delta in in this columns in milliseconds:

```
select extract(milliseconds from modified_at - created_at) as delta_millsfrom shop_order
```

Nice. Now I want to get delta current date and column **created_at**

I try this:

```
select id, extract(milliseconds from (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp) * 1000) - created_at) as detla_mills from shop_order
```

But get error

```
:
ERROR:  operator does not exist: double precision - timestamp without time zone
LINE 1: ...om (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp) * 1000) - created_...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 85
```

Comment: Just looking at the syntax of the second expression, I'm very suspicious of the `* 1000` applied to the `EPOCH` extracted from `current_timestamp`.  I would doubt that it would result in the correct `timestamp` type.  Given the error message complaining about double precision minus timestamp, I'd guess that the multiplication is giving you a `double` from which you can't directly subtract a `timestamp`.  Perhaps there's a way to cast it to back to a `timestamp`?

Comment: @RobParker this work: select id, created_at,
extract(milliseconds from (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - created_at) as delta
from shop_order

Comment: Should I put my comment as an answer then to get credit?  I hadn't because I don't specifically know PostgreSQL and couldn't give a valid example solution... just a hint from realizing what the error was complaining about in the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

From the text of the error and examining the syntax of the failing expression, the problem is that `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp)` is probably not a `timestamp` type, and definitely multiplying it by `* 1000` can't sensibly result in a `timestamp` type (what date would be (Sep 16, 2020) times 1000, eh?).  According to the error, it's a `double precision`, from which you can't then subtract a `timestamp`.

You need to subtract some base `timestamp` value from `current_timestamp` and then convert it to another type or part that you want, or else convert the base and `current_timestamp` in the same way to another type that can be directly subtracted for the delta (such as converting the extracted `EPOCH` back to a base `timestamp` at the start of that `EPOCH`.